# VS Code ignore a word in search

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to search my project for the word `resolver` but I want to ignore the result `UserEntityRouteNameResolverService`. Is this doable in VS code?

Comment: sure, you just have to click the "match case" option on the right of your search field.
Since "Resolver" is uppercase and "resolver" lowercase, this just would to the trick.

Comment: Use `Match case`  & `Match Whole Word` options next to search box

Comment: Oh yea match upper case works fine :) thanks.

Comment: do a regex search, case insensitive for `(?<!UserEntityRouteName)resolver`

Answer (score 0):

You could try `~(UserEntityRouteName)resolver`.

`~(string)` indicates that it should NOT match <string>.